# Hive sql joining table finding closest row

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have the following tables :

Tbl1 :

```
V1 | V2 | Time
x    A    1
x    B    4
y    C    5
```

Tbl2 :

```
V1 | Time 
x    2
x    4
y    1
```

I want to join them in a way that I get the following result

```
Tbl2.V1 | Tbl1.V2 | Tbl2.Time
x         A         2
x         B         4
y         null      1
```

In other words I want to join the tables on V1 and get the V2 from Tbl2 where Tbl1.Time < Tbl2.Time and (Tbl2.Time - Tbl1.Time) gets the minimum value. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide some sample data.

Comment: I was trying with `group by`,  `Min` and `union all` but i think you should show us some better table structure of these tables.

Answer (score 0):

In other databases, you would use correlated subqueries.  That is not an option.  Creating a Cartesian product and then aggregating is another approach -- and it works for smaller tables.

Another approach is to interleave the two tables, use a cumulative function, and then select from the first table:

```
select v1, v2, time, t2time
from (select v1, v2, time,
             max(time) over (partition by v1
                             order by time, v2 as nulls first
                            ) as t2time
      from ((select v1, v2, time
             from table1
            ) union all
            (select v1, NULL, time
             from table2
            )
           ) t
     ) t
where v2 is not null;  -- Remove table2 records
```

I have not used this approach in Hive.  I have found it to be very effective in Oracle, SQL Server, and Postgres.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and the suggestions. Unfortunately the above query doesn't seem to be working with Hive. I 'll try to tweak it a bit and see if I can make it run.